# Ten year anniversary

Tags: discussion

This year will mark 10 years of the SP.SE site being active.

The mods have received some communication from SE that they'd like to celebrate this. So I have some questions for the community:

- Do we want the banner? `we are planning on adding a “10 year Anniversary” banner to the sites who want it`
- `What makes your community special?`

Thoughts? Suggestions? Comments?

Answer (score 4):

> What makes your community special?

it's *small*

everyone knows everyone, sees everything

get off my lawn

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- I'd like that banner :D
- Our community is special because

  - the quality of answers here is extremely high, while we still cater to everyone's questions, from beginners to industry veterans.
  - We, as community, found our niche that's neither too narrow (we're *not* just signal theory, or just audio processing, or just DSP coding) nor too wide (we do care about image processing and biomedical signals, and have world-class contributors there, but we do not try to be the go-to people for picture retouching, or practicalities of video processing, or neurology) in a very "organic" manner – the members of the community have always been helping these that ask "on the edge" questions as well as possible, but tried to still point them in the right direction if that direction was elsewhere.
    That comes with a downside – we don't attract everyone – but with a high emotional return-on-investment for writing an answer.
    This feels like a *choice* – other SE sites don't go our route of voluntarily focusing what we're best at, but try to focus on the breadth of topics *of interest* to practicioners of their discipline; that's a fine, choice, too (Ham.SE does that, for example; a lot of the things that would be fine in EE.SE are fine in Ham.SE, too, and the overlap is intended), but it makes for a different community. We're special!